Calculating the electronic potential energy for hydrogen system using plane waves: What causes the poor convergence?
Problem definition
I am studying how plane waves and fast Fourier transforms (FFT) can be used as a basis set in quantum chemical calculations. As a toy problem, I aim to calculate the electronic potential energy for the 1s atomic orbital in a H atom. The H atom is placed at the center of a cubic unit cell with an edge size of $a_{0}$. This system has an analytical solution ($E_{\text{pot}} = -1$ Ht), which allows for an easy comparison.
In the graph as seen below, I plot the potential energy (in Ht) as function of the number of sampling points per Cartesian direction, both used in the Fourier transform as well as in the real-space numerical integration. Furthermore, I perform this analysis for varying edge size ($a_{0}$) of the cubic unit cell.
Questions

Why does the energy converge to a less negative value when using smaller unit cells? My - perhaps naive - intuition would say that if I use a smaller unit cell, the electron density experiences more (favorable) attraction due to a larger charge density. I would thus expect that the result converges to a more negative number.
Why does a larger unit cell require significantly more plane waves to reach convergence with respect to the number of plane waves? I reasoned that for a larger unit cell, the plane waves have fewer oscillation, giving a worse sampling of the space, thus requiring more plane waves. Is that reasoning valid?
I understand that in typical plane-wave electronic structure calculations pseudo-potentials are being used. I am under the impression that for the H-atom, due to its relatively limited charge, one can still do without, but perhaps that is not the case. Can this be the reason for the relatively poor convergence?


Other remarks

For reproduction purposes, I have included a (condensed) derivation of the equations used in my approach as well as a copy of the Python script to reproduce the figure shown above.

Derivation of equations used in numerical procedure
Given the charge density corresponding to a single nuclear charge
$$
\rho_{\text{nucleus}}(\vec{r}) = \delta(\vec{r} - \vec{R}).
$$
with $\vec{R}$ being the position of the nucleus. I can represent this charge density as a plane wave expansion via
$$
\rho(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\Omega}} \sum_{\vec{G}} \tilde{\rho}(\vec{G}) \exp \left(i \vec{G} \cdot \vec{R} \right).
$$
To obtain the real-space nuclear attraction potential, I solve Poisson's equation in reciprocal-space (removing the divergent term corresponding to $\vec{G} = \vec{0}$) and perform a backward Fourier transform, i.e.
$$
\nu(\vec{r}) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[\frac{-4\pi}{\sqrt{\Omega}} \sum_{\vec{G} \neq \vec{0}} \frac{\tilde{\rho}(\vec{G})}{|\vec{G}|^{2}} \exp \left(i \vec{G} \cdot \vec{R} \right) \right].
$$
Finally, I calculate the nuclear attraction by evaluating
$$
E_{\text{nuc}} = \int_{\Omega} d\vec{r} \; |\psi_{\text{1s}}(\vec{r})|^{2} \; \nu(\vec{r})
$$
Numerical implementation in Python
To reproduce the graph as shown in the problem definition, please find below the Python script that I am using. As a kind warning, I perform this analysis up to 512 sampling points per Cartesian direction, generating ~134 million plane waves which is associated with a substantial memory footprint. Depending on your hardware, please take this into consideration before running the script on your own machine.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sc
import tqdm

def main():    
    nptss = np.logspace(3,9,7, base=2)      # number of sampling points per cartesian direction
    a0s = [10,20,50,100,200]                # edge sizes of cubic unit cell
    vnuc = np.zeros((len(a0s), len(nptss))) # data container
    for i,s in enumerate(tqdm.tqdm(a0s)):
        v = []
        for j,npts in enumerate(nptss):
            vnuc[i,j] = calculate_nuclear_attraction(int(npts), s)
        
    # build graph
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,dpi=144)
    for i,s in enumerate(a0s):
        ax.plot(nptss, vnuc[i,:], 'o--', label=r'$a_{0} = %.1f$ a.u.' % s)
    ax.grid(linestyle='--')
    ax.set_xscale('symlog')
    ax.set_yscale('symlog')
    ax.set_xlabel('Number of sampling points per cartesian direction [-]')
    ax.set_ylabel(r'$E_{\text{pot}}$ [Ht]')
    ax.legend(loc='lower right')        
    plt.tight_layout()

def calculate_nuclear_attraction(npts, sz):
    """
    Calculate the potential energy of a 1s atomic orbital
    """
    r, k, k2 = build_lattice_points(sz, npts)
    
    # generate wave function
    R = np.array([sz/2,sz/2,sz/2])
    rRv =  r - R
    Rr = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ijkl,ijkl->ijk', rRv, rRv))
    wf = 1.0 / np.sqrt(np.pi) * np.exp(-Rr)
    
    # generate structure factor and nuclear attraction field
    sf = np.exp(-1j * k @ R) / np.sqrt(sz**3)
    ct = np.sqrt(sz**3) / npts**3
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
        nupotg = -4.0 * np.pi / k2
        nupotg[0,0,0] = 0
    vnuc = sc.fft.ifftn(sf * nupotg) / ct
    
    dV = (sz/npts)**3 # real-space integration constant
    Enuc = np.einsum('ijk,ijk,ijk', wf, wf, vnuc).real * dV
    
    return Enuc

def build_lattice_points(sz, npts):
    """
    Build the lattice points, both in real-space as well as in reciprocal space.
    Also calculate the squared reciprocal space vector magnitudes
    """
    # determine grid points in real space
    c = np.linspace(0, sz, npts, endpoint=False)

    # construct real space sampling vectors
    z, y, x = np.meshgrid(c, c, c, indexing='ij')
    
    N = len(c)
    cvec = np.zeros((npts, npts, npts, 3))
    cvec[:,:,:,0] = x
    cvec[:,:,:,1] = y
    cvec[:,:,:,2] = z
    
    # calculate plane wave vector coefficients in one dimension
    k = np.fft.fftfreq(npts) * 2.0 * np.pi * (npts / sz)
    
    # construct plane wave vectors
    k3, k2, k1 = np.meshgrid(k, k, k, indexing='ij')
    
    N = len(k)
    kvec = np.zeros((N,N,N,3))
    kvec[:,:,:,0] = k1
    kvec[:,:,:,1] = k2
    kvec[:,:,:,2] = k3
    
    k2 = np.einsum('ijkl,ijkl->ijk', kvec, kvec)
    
    return cvec, kvec, k2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Your question is unclear.  There is only one proton in hydrogen, so what nuclear attraction are we talking about here?   Also a proton is not attracted to an orbital, it is attracted to another charged particle.  Finally, why would you think that plane waves, which are useful for scattering states, would be useful for bound states?

I think you are extremely mistaken over what it is you are doing. You seem to be computing only the energies in the electronic wavefunction, and if you are doing that, then you won't be doing any "nuclear attraction". I also don't see where your analytical result could be correct; the H atom $13.6e$V is one Rydberg, half a Hartree. A larger unit cell is a smaller Brillouin zone and so it really only looks like you need a larger number of plane waves to reach a same radius in the Brillouin zone. H pseudopotentials help get rid of the annoying singularity.

@ZeroTheHero The nuclear attraction is due to the positive charge on the nucleus with the negative charge of the electron density of a single electron, as described by the 1s wave function. The reason I think that plane waves would be suitable to describe this problem is because plane wave basis sets are used abundantly in electronic structure calculations.

@naturallyInconsistent On the basis of the comments raised here, I see that the term "nuclear attraction" is apparently confusing, so I have rephrased the question. The term is actually pretty common in electronic structure calculations, see for example the seminal work of Szabo and Ostlund, yet to avoid any further confusion I refer to it now as the electronic potential energy. I hope that is clearer.

@naturallyInconsistent The total electronic energy, i.e. kinetic + potential, corresponds indeed to E = -1/2Ht. If you add the kinetic energy, which corresponds to $E_{k} = \frac{1}{2}$ Ht, you'll indeed find the E = -1/2 Ht. You can also easily verify that my analytical solution is correct by solving $E_{p} = \int d\vec{r} \frac{1}{r} r^{2} |\psi|^{2} = 1$. See also this link.

Ah, I had assumed that you would do the more usual thing and have the kinetic energy added; it is very weird that you solved only for the potential energy without the kinetic energy term. But I think your convergence is normal and ok; and also showing why we want a pseudopotential even for H atom. It would just help with convergence. The physically meaningful stuff for considering electronic bonds, are the long-distance-from-nucleus limit, not the short distance limits that are mathematically required to behave in known ways.

@naturallyInconsistent Thank you for that valuable feedback. :-) I'll keep it in mind that just solving for one part of the electronic structure problem is considered weird and will cause confusion. So if I understand your comment correctly, the poor convergence of plane waves is 'known' or at least 'to be expected' and this serves as the natural motivation to use pseudo-potentials, already for H atoms.
